# Any hierarchical Data Support in Doctrine 2?

Tags: doctrine

in Doctrine 1, i see that it supports hierarchical data support? is there any in Doctrine 2?

## UPDATE 1

ok so i used [Nested Set Extension for Doctrine 2](http://github.com/blt04/doctrine2-nestedset). i have some questions

**1. inserting a node**

```
// in the docs
$child1 = new Category();
$child1->name = 'Child Category 1';

$child2 = new Category();
$child2->name = 'Child Category 2';

$category->addChild($child1);
$category->addChild($child2);
```

it seems like i must do something like

```
$root = $nsm->createRoot($category);
$root->addChild($child1);
$root->addChild($child2);
```

likewise to add sub children

```
$child2wrapper = $root->addChild($child2);
$child2wrapper->addChild($newChild);
```

**2. abt the root field and having multiple trees.**

say i want multiple trees, i see that the extension does not populate my `root` field? how shld i populate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see this links :

http://github.com/guilhermeblanco/Doctrine2-Hierarchical-Structural-Behavior

http://www.devcomments.com/Any-hierarchical-data-support-in-Doctrine-2-at251409.htm

Comment: ok i used the extension from the link and have afew further questions. see my update (1)

Comment: sorry but i never use it, i hope others user help :)

Comment: i found my answers to update @ [Google Groups - Doctrine Users](http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/msg/7fbc1e620016cd2d)