# Hierarchical data with Doctrine in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I would like to know how to setup hierarchical data in Symfony 2.3 with Doctrine.
I read that Doctrine provides some engine to manage this kind of data here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/hierarchical-data.html

but I can't read anything about it in the offical documentation.
There are many posts about hierarchical data in Symfony, but there are related with Symfony 1.x.

How should it be done in Symfony 2.3?

Comment: I think Symfony2 uses doctrine 2+ , that documentation corresponds to version 1+ . Did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350157/any-hierarchical-data-support-in-doctrine-2

Comment: look at my answer ! I have already used this extension. let me know if you have any question !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Look at this](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md) : the doctrine nestead set is what you are looking for !

Comment: I read about gedmo, but I thought Symfony 2.3 has something like this built-in.